# Why does this embeded google maps item break in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps

A coworker asked me to help try and fix this, and we are both stumped.  This works perfectly in firefox, chrome, and opera, yet sadly it breaks in IE.  Here is the [page](http://www.3d-4d-ultrasounds.com/alabama/locations.php)

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, I get this error: "Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://www.3d-4d-ultrasounds.com.", as a result of a cross-domain scripting attempt.

Could be some bung JavaScript not being picked up by IE, but having an effect?